# .Net Lambda Container Image Does Not See My Environment Variables

Tags: c#, .net, aws-lambda

I am very new to .Net Lambdas in container images, and I'm stuck on almost the first step. I have created a new .Net Lambda project in Visual Studio 2019 and tried to add an environment variable to the docker file

```
ENV ENVIRONMENT=dev
```

and it is not available in my lambda code when running.

```
$"{Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ENVIRONMENT")}_"
```

I tried the "built-in" AWS_REGION environmental variable and it worked. What do I need to do to get my own environment variables to show up in the code?